# CCNode recursive getChildByTag

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccnode

As far as I understand the `CCNode::getChildByTag` method only searches among direct children.

But is there any way to recursively find a CCNode's child by tag in all its descendant hierarchy ?

I'm loading a CCNode from a CocosBuilder ccb file and I'd like to retrieve subnodes knowing only their tags (not their position/level in the hierarchy)

Comment: if you need that, you can easily implement a recursive `getChildByTag` that visits the whole hierarchy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way - to create your own method. Or create category for CCNode with this method. It will look like smth like this

```
- (CCNode*) getChildByTagRecursive:(int) tag
{
    CCNode* result = [self getChildByTag:tag];

    if( result == nil )
    {
        for(CCNode* child in [self children])
        {
            result = [child getChildByTagRecursive:tag];
            if( result != nil )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Add this method to the CCNode category. You can create category in any file you want but I recommend to create separate file with this category only. In this case any other object where this header will be imported, will be able to send this message to any CCNode subclass.

Actually, any object will be able to send this message but it will cause warnings during compilation in case of not importing header.

Comment: you're not calling it recursively

Comment: In which class would this method go ?

Comment: Oh ok. I had never header of categories so far, I'm not really an Objective C master :). Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a cocos2d-x 3.x implementation for a recursive getChildByTag function:

```
/** 
 * Recursively searches for a child node
 * @param typename T (optional): the type of the node searched for.
 * @param nodeTag: the tag of the node searched for.
 * @param parent: the initial parent node where the search should begin.
 */
template <typename T = cocos2d::Node*>
static inline T getChildByTagRecursively(const int nodeTag, cocos2d::Node* parent) {
    auto aNode = parent->getChildByTag(nodeTag);
    T nodeFound = dynamic_cast<T>(aNode);
    if (!nodeFound) {
        auto children = parent->getChildren();
        for (auto child : children)
        {
            nodeFound = getChildByTagRecursively<T>(nodeTag, child);
            if (nodeFound) break;
        }
    }
    return nodeFound;
}
```

As an option you can also pass in the type of the node searched for as an argument.