# What is the C++ equivalent of this Objective-C Cocos2D and CCNode

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to translate some code from Objective-C to C++

I have a CCNode and I want to recursively traverse all the nodes it has.

I cannot figure out how to write this:

```
 for(CCNode* child in [self children])
 {

 }
```

Can anyone translate this for me?

Update: this is the code from another SO answer: [CCNode recursive getChildByTag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309180/ccnode-recursive-getchildbytag)

Comment: `[self children]` in Obj-C is like `this->children` in C++, I believe; so you need a data member `children` which is a container of `CCNode *`, I guess.

Comment: `[self children]` is an accessor method invocation, which is potentially a bit different from `this->children`, but the subtleties there are unlikely to affect the OP's translation problem.

Comment: I updated with the other SO question I am getting this from.

Comment: Is there a C++ implementation of CCNode?

Comment: @cppguy - sure: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d0/ded/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_node.html

Answer (score 3):

Since there isn't fast enumeration in C++, you can iterate it through an iterator, or a counter, stopping when the counter reaches the collection size. Then get every object with *objectAtIndex()*:

```
for(int i = 0; i < getChildren()->count(); i++)
{
    CCNode *child = getChildren()->objectAtIndex(i);
    < Your code >
}
```

Comment: this-> is redundant in C++ in most cases

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, we have range-based `for` loops that have a similar syntax.

To do this, you need an iterator-based wrapper.

The easiest way to do this is to use `# include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>`.  Wrapping an index-based container in an `iterator_facade` at `begin`/`end` is pretty easy.

If you have written a `struct my_iterator:boost::iterator_facade<my_iterator> {...};` type, then just write `my_iterator begin( CCArray& )`, the `const` versions, and the `end` version.

Having done this, you get:

for( CCObject* obj : *getChildren() )
which is close, but uses `CCObject` instead of `CCNode`.  You happen to know that the children of `this` are `CCNode`, but the Cocos2d interface only tells you the children are `CCObject`s.

I'd write an `CCArrayAs<T>` adapter function that returns a wrapped `CCArray` with a type `T` information.  Ie:

```
template<typename T>
struct CCArrayAs {
  CCArray* arr;
};
```

which you'll notice does not use the type `T` anywhere.  We once again write iterators, but for the above `struct`, where the return type instead of being a `CCObject*` is a `T*` using `static_cast`.  We then write `begin( CCArrayAs& )`, `end`, and `const` versions, and what we get out of it is:

```
for( CCNode* node : CCArrayAs<CCNode>(getChildren()) )
```

which is pretty close to the Objective-C syntax.  If you want a prettier syntax, write `CCArrayAs<CCNode> GetChildren( CCNode* self ) { return self->getChildren(); }`, giving you:

```
for( CCNode* node : GetChildren(this) )
```

The downside to this is that it is a lot of boilerplate, all to get a slightly prettier syntax.  It is something you'd hope Cocos2d developers would do, rather than having to do yourself.

If you don't want to do all that work, you can simply loop over the indexes.  See @RamyAlZuhouri's answer for that solution.  It is much, much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming you are using the c++ port of Cocos2d-iPhone?
If this is the case then you could use Cocos2d-x's macro for iterating over CCArrays.

Example:

```
CCObject* pObj = nullptr;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(getChildren(), pObj)
{
    // do something
}
```